# Print images stored in cell array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, image-processing

**Background:**

I am programming SIFT in matlab. I have computed the Difference of Gaussians and have stored them in a 2D cell array. The images in column 2 are half the size of column 1 and so on.

**Questions.**

Now that I have all of the images stored in my 2D cell array I would like to print them all in one figure.

Im been browsing the web for quite a bit but I haven't seen anything that could help. If anyone could point me in the right direction or provide an example it would be greatly appriciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a really simple solution then just make a composite image and fill in the regions with the images in the gaussian pyramid. I've given an example code below the works for my case but needs to be adapted for yours.

Code:

```
% Get total width and height    
width_total = 0;                       
height_total = 0;             
for i = 0:3 % Cycle over scales - 4 total
    width_total = width_total+size(obj.gaussianpyramid{i+1,1},2);
    height_total = height_total+size(obj.gaussianpyramid{i+1,1},1);
end

% Form composite gaussian
compositegaussian = zeros(width_total,height_total);   

ind_x = 0;
for i = 0:3 % Cycle over octaves - 4 total                   
    for j = 0:4 % Cycle over scales - 5 total
        ind_y = j*size(obj.gaussianpyramid{i+1,j+1},1);
        compositegaussian(ind_y+1:ind_y+size(obj.gaussianpyramid{i+1,j+1},1),ind_x+1:ind_x+size(obj.gaussianpyramid{i+1,j+1},2)) = obj.gaussianpyramid{i+1,j+1};
    end
    ind_x = ind_x + size(obj.gaussianpyramid{i+1,1},2); 
end 

figure, imshow(compositegaussian,[]);
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Lets generate random `5x2` cell array where the first columns contains 10x10 images and the second - 5x5 images:

```
c = cell(5,2);
for k=1:5
    c{k,1} = uint8(255 * rand(10));
    c{k,2} = uint8(255 * rand(5));
end
```

The following code illustrates them:

```
figure;
n = size(c, 1);
for k = 1 : n
    subplot(n, 2, k * 2 - 1);
    image(c{k,1});
    subplot(n, 2, k * 2);
    image(c{k,2});    
end
```

If the images are upside down, use `set(gca,'YDir','normal');` after each `image()` call.